# How can I get the date in javascript in a specified format: day. month year?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am converting a UNIX timestamp to a date object. I managed to do the splitting of the returned date with `split()`. This is what I have:

```
var randomDate = new Date(1571990933 * 1000).toString().split('T');
console.log(randomDate[0]);
```

What I get: `Wed Oct 30 2019 14:30:30 GM`

What I want: `30. October 2019`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a months array mapping (index to human readable month name), then build your string using date.get methods for day month and year

```
const getDate = () => {
  const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  const date = new Date(1571990933 * 1000);
  return `${date.getDay()}. ${months[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If including a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is an option, it has everything sorted out for you :

```js
console.log( moment( new Date(1571990933 * 1000) ).format('D[.] MMMM YYYY') )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```